# Using Transactions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, transactions

`SELECT` executed during the first command T1 is a transaction, in turn, `DELETE` command (at the time T2) is the first command transaction B. What will be the result of the `SELECT` statement at the time of T3 (a transaction)?

[alt text http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/3382/sqlm.png](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/3382/sqlm.png)

The `SELECT` statement in T3 will return a row (because Transaction B is not committed yet) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will, as the other transaction is not commited yet.

If you would try to do the same `DELETE` in `Transaction A` after the `DELETE` in `Transaction B`, then you would have to wait for the lock to be released, but a `SELECT` will work fine.